# Replace occurrence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and this string could contain some occurrences like:

`http://site/image.jpg`

What is the right way to replace, when it's present, this kind of occurrence by

`<img src="http://site/image.jpg">`

What is really important, is to replace only occurrences beginning by `http` and which ending by `.jpg`, `.png` and `gif` by the `<img>` HTML tag.

So if among all the text there is a URL link of any images, it's formatted by a HTML tag to display the image.

Comment: You should look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which can be used to work with strings

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward with regex:

```
import re

string = 'some other text, a URL http://site/image.jpg and other text'

print(re.sub(r'(https?.+?(?:jpg|png|gif))', r'<img src="\1">', string))

# some other text, a URL <img src="http://site/image.jpg"> and other text
```

`(https?.+(?:jpg|png|gif))` matches everything that starts with `http` or `https` and ending with `jpg`, `png` or `gif`.

`'<img src="\1">'` here the `\1` refers to the first (and only) capture group in the previous regex (which contains the image url).

Comment: Unfortunately your regexp matches literally everything that starts with http and ending with .jpg/png/gif, so if there is more than one link separated by some text - this text also will be captured. Please check example: https://regex101.com/r/eYVuXF/1

Comment: @erhesto Ok, fixed. Was only a matter of changing `.+` to the lazy `.+?` https://regex101.com/r/eYVuXF/2

Comment: Still not totally comfortable situation, as things like in example: https://regex101.com/r/eYVuXF/3 are captured, but maybe it will be enough for OP, so I'm removing downvote.

Comment: @erhesto Well, OP did not ask for a url verifier.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I think to get a solution by AJAX/JQUERY

Answer (score 1):

**This is a simple answer to your question:**

```
def check_if_image(url, image_extensions):
   if url.startswith("https://") or url.startswith("http://"):
       for extension in image_extensions:
           if(extension in url[-4:]):
               return True
   return False

def main():
   url_seed = ["http://somesite.com/img1.jpg", "https://somesite2.com/img2.gif", 
            "http://somesite3.net/img3.png", "http://noimagesite.com/noimage"]
   image_extensions = [".jpg", ".png", ".gif"]

   final_result=[]
   for site in url_seed:
       if check_if_image(site, image_extensions):
           final_result.append('<img src="%s">' %site)
   print(final_result)
```

This includes "http" and "https" site verification, as well as code working for 3 character image extensions, such as you asked: jpg, gif and png.

Hope it helped.
Feel free to ask if you have any question.

**Edit: Didn't notice you had not the urls already in a data structure, so this is invalid to your situation**

Comment: You can use `startswith(http) or startswith(https)` in check_if_image. It's faster than a regex and it's a good way to.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Since I'm switching languages a lot I don't always know the built-ins of them. Will take note :)

Comment: Python is great language. But regex is little bit slower than [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). But sometime you can take an other way than regex :D

Comment: Already updated my answer according to your tip, even if it's not the solution for this answer, but might help someone else with a similar question when googling. Thank you

Comment: My URLS are in a string like "Hi, my name is Clement and my avatar is http://image.jpg and there is another picture : http://image2.png.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I think to get a solution by AJAX/JQUERY